# IIS 7.5 Authorization Rules not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have a basic Visual Studio project, 2 folders in a site, one folder called 'pub' which should be publicly available, and one called 'auth' which requires you to sign in to view the contents. I have 2 location rules in the web.config that manage that.
I am also using a basic auth module (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) which is added to modules in IIS and registered

In VS when I debug using IISExpress, everything works as expected, 'pub' let's me in no problem, and auth prompts me for credentials using 'basic' auth. But when I publish (through VS, delete all files prior to update) the site to IIS 7.5 every folder requires authentication, which is wrong.

Now if it is the BasicAuthModule that is causing the issue, then how do I get prompted for credentials using basic auth in IISExpress, but if it isn't the module then what is different between the IISExpress debug install and my servers?

There isn't really a lot of code to show, but here is my web.config with the code that we are using:

```
-system.webServer-
    -modules-
        -add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="WebHostBasicAuth.BasicAuthHttpModule" -
    -/modules-
-/system.webServer-

-system.web-
    -httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" -
    -authentication mode="Windows" -
-/system.web-

-location path="~/services/public"-
   -system.web-
      -authorization-
        -allow users="*"-
      -/authorization-
   -/system.web-
-/location-

-location path="~/services/auth"-
    -system.web-
      -authorization-
        -deny users="?"-
      -/authorization-
    -/system.web-
-/location-
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer, redesigned the site to have virtual directories for the auth and pub and changed the auth methods for each one.

I just though there should be a better way.